# Show the most recent Note

Tags: sql, sql-server

My task is to show the most recent note from the below query.

```
SELECT repair.jobnumber
    ,repair.jobname
    ,property.address
    ,n.memnote
    ,repair.DATE
    ,property.propertypk
FROM property
LEFT JOIN repair ON repair.propertyfk = property.propertypk
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT memnote
        ,max(DATE) AS DATE
        ,notetype
        ,notepk
        ,propertyfk
    FROM note
    WHERE notetype = 'PS'
    GROUP BY memnote
        ,notetype
        ,notepk
        ,propertyfk
    ) n ON n.propertyfk = property.propertypk
WHERE repairtype = 'garden'
```

But it still shows all notes with the type PS not each repair and the most recent not on the property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `row_number()`:

```
select r.jobnumber, r.jobname, p.address, n.memnote, r.date, p.propertypk
from property p join
     repair r
     on r.propertyfk = p.propertypk left join
     (select n.*, row_number() over (partiiton by n.propertypk order by n.date desc) as seqnum
      from note
      where notetype = 'PS' 
     ) n
     on n.propertyfk = p.propertypk and n.seqnum = 1
where r.repairtype = 'garden';
```

Note:  You are filtering on `repairtype` in the `where` clause, so I changed the `join` to be an inner join.  If you want all properties, then move that condition to the `on` and use `left join`.

Comment: can you explain why this is better than other ways please

Comment: i will try it now

Comment: @JD_123 . . . There are no alternative solutions that are answers on your question.  I would say that this is pretty simple to implement and it should have reasonable performance, taking advantage of indexes.